# Nginx React App - 403 Permissions Denied (only for some files)

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I will start off with a note that I have looked through an excessive amount of questions that have already been asked.

I have set up a droplet on Digital Ocean and currently trying to configure my `React` application to run on it with `nginx`. It was running fine before I decided to remove my static files and replace it with another folder (instead of replacing file-by-file... damn).

My `nginx` configuration `user` is `nginx` and I believe I've set the correct permissions for all static data in the directory where it reads from. However, I still think the problem lies with permissions and hoping someone could help to figure out the problem.

**Permissions on the directories**
[image]

`nginx.conf` has the following set: `user nginx;`

`nginx` running processes with what users are running them:

```
root     23264     1  0 13:11 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
nginx    23265 23264  0 13:11 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
```

Maybe some directories/files are to remain 'chowned' to `root`?

This is also the network result from my browser:
[image]

It looks as if some files can be accessed but the js minified files cannot be?

Answer (score 0):

Right, finally found the answer to my own question...
For anyone who faces the same issue, the following command on `static` folder inside `grade-ui` fixed it:

```
chmod -R +rx css
```